# Did I kill my CPU by cleaning the computer?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, cpu, cleaning

I have a computer running Windows 7 which was working fine until I cleaned it. Now I'm getting blue screens and error messages. Running Ubuntu on live disk says the CPU is bad.

I was asked to do a system upgrade on an HP desktop computer (uninstalled Vista and installed Windows 7) and the computer was working fine for pretty much all day. Since it was dusty when I got it, I figured I'd clean it before giving it back (used compressed air, I know about the vacuum issue).

When I gave the computer back to my uncle it was boot looping. I managed to get it to boot properly while I was over there, but it blue screened right after that.

I took it back, booted it where it with the peripherals I was using (in case the issue was due to some external device) and got the same issue. I tried booting with a Ubuntu live disk, booted up fine so I did a self-test on the hard drive and the computer started to reboot after like 30-60 seconds. My natural inclination was to say the hard drive was bad, however upon rebooting into Ubuntu I got a crash (off the live disk with no hard drive mounted) saying that the CPU was bad.

At this point I figured I might as well do a stress test so I opened system settings to see how many cores there were, in order to do the test, and upon closing the window it crashed again, same message. So at this point do I just assume the CPU is bad? I'm reluctant because it's so rare that these things fail, especially after a cleaning seems a little far fetched.

Error message

- Starting crash report submission daemon [OK]
- Checking battery state... [OK]
- Stopping System V runlevel compatibility [OK]
- Stopping cold plug devices [OK]
- Stopping log initial device creation [OK]
- Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices [OK]
- Starting configure network device security [OK]
- Starting save udev log and update rules [OK]
- Stopping save udev log and update rules [OK]
- Stopping enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices [OK]

[image: hardware error kernel panic]

Comment: First thought is that something came unseated during the cleaning

Comment: try reseating your CPU (and reseating the heatsink in the process). It is possible that the heatsink has started to lose contact with the CPU during the cleaning. The stress test may have generated sufficient heat to trigger the thermal shutdown, or in the worst case, damaged the CPU. Also confirm that the heatsink fan and CPU 4/8-pin power rail did not come unplugged during the cleaning. Reseating the ram may also be warrented, if reseating the CPU doesn't address the issue. If nothing else, deprive it of power for an hour. it surprises me how often that works.

Comment: @FrankThomas I never actually managed to start the stress test (just realized how ambiguous it was in my post fixing it now). I had already checked all the connections but thank for the heads up. I'll try removing and cleaning the heat-sink/CPU tomorrow and report back.

Comment: If this was "shop" compressed air, i.e. 40-100 psi (3-7 bar), then it likely yanked on components hard enough to unseat them, or even break a weak solder bond (particularly on a larger component such as an electrolytic capacitor). Check not only that all RAM and other socketed components are properly seated but also that solder connections are firm.

Comment: @DudeRandom21 Can you describe everything you did while cleaning it in as much detail as possible?

Comment: When you reseat the CPU make sure you didn't bend one of the pins in the socket. They're very fragile on modern sockets. Reseat and or swap out the ram, but look real close at the CPU pins. Just one of them can be off, yet you'll get power/boot and random errors.

Comment: I also wouldn't be worried about the power of the compressor. I stop in at friend's shops and use massive compressors to blow out all of my hardware, just make sure you slide a screwdriver or something into fan grates to keep them from spinning and going wildly out of control (as they're pretty much the only think you're going to damage).

Comment: I'd just reseat the RAM before messing with the CPU.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback! Yes I used a shop compressor with with a blow gun but I never open the valve to 100% (no real need, dust starts flying at like 30% open). When I clean it I open the valve on the gun about 30% at 1-2 feet away from the cases (pointing toward it) this usually gets all the loose dust out and on a dirty machine like this one makes a large cloud. After that I move the gun a little closer and focus on any spots that still have dust. Usually the CPU fan/heat-sink, case fan (which I was amazed to see this OEM built computer does not have), and psu fan and intake vent.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Don't worry about the CPU pins I've custom build and rebuild computer's a few times in the past, I've just never had one die on my before after cleaning... Thanks for the heads up though and also for the advice on stopping the fans, never really thought of the damage they could get from spinning to fast.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I went with your advice and reseated the RAM before doing anything else which yielded an extended error message (added to my OP) IMHO this is likely just a coincidence but thanks for the idea none the less!

Comment: Quick Little Advise did you at any point while using the air touch anything or have anything touch the board that could have a ESD Effect that you may have been unaware of?

Comment: No I did not (I never touch the air gun to the computer). Actually I didn't give updates in a while because I was having trouble getting the cpu off the heatsink (it was REALLY caked on). so I brought it to a local tech shop and the clerk helped me out. He suggested I check for blown caps on the mobo (don't know why I didn't think of it before) and turns out there were 3 blown caps on the board. So I ordered a few to change them and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Alright well turns out the issue had really nothing to do with the CPU as such, it was actually some blown caps on the motherboard, there were 3 caps that had either a bulge or leakage (hadn't noticed them at first). So I swapped them out and the computer runs good as new, stress tested and everything!

I still don't know if it was the cleaning that shorted something or if it was the cold outside (live in Canada) or what exactly caused the caps to blow.

My take from this is to always remember to check the caps on the motherboard when things go wrong.